# Python Speech Recognizer taking system speaker voice as input instead of Microphone What to do?

Tags: python

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

def takecommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
        print("Listening...")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.energy_threshold = 200
        audio = r.listen(source)


    try:
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
        print(f"User Said: {query}\n")

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)

        speak("Please Say that Again")
        print("Say that Again...")
        return "None"
    return query
```

When I Try To Use the Above Code my speech recognizer takes speakers voice as input instead of microphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Python SpeechRecognition [doc](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/1.2.3/):

A device index is an integer between 0 and pyaudio.get_device_count() - 1 (assume we have used import pyaudio beforehand) inclusive. It represents an audio device such as a microphone or speaker. See the PyAudio [documentation](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/) for more details.

If device_index is unspecified or None, the default microphone is used as the audio source. Otherwise, device_index should be the index of the device to use for audio input.

You are using the device with index 1:

```
with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
```

What I suggest is to query the available audio devices, and change the index accordingly:

1. List available devices using the pyaudio package(pip install pyaudio)

```
import pyaudio
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
pa.get_device_count() #get available devices
```

2. Change your device index accordingly(most probably your other device is index 0 or 2):

```
with sr.Microphone(device_index=0) as source: #replace 0 with the index of the device you want to use
```

Comment: Nope It's Not Working after the changes